# Add HTML OnClick With +1 ID by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create code for add new input with custom style but i need to change id number and "for" Tag value OnClick.

I need to add id="input-2" and for="input-2"
and in on click i need to add new html with id="input-3" and for="input-3"

This Code:

```js
var maxSocial = 10,
    socialWrapper = $("#socialWrapper"),
    addSocial = $("#add-social"),
    socialX = 1;

$(addSocial).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (socialX < maxSocial) {
        socialX++;
        $(socialWrapper).append('<div class="inputbox"><div class= "inputbox-content"><input id="input-1" type="text" required /><label for="input-1">Social Link</label><span class="underline"></span></div></div>');
    }
});

$(socialWrapper).on("click", ".remove-social", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); socialX--;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="socialWrapper">
  <div class="inputbox">
    <div class="inputbox-content">
      <input id="input-1" type="text" required />
      <label for="input-1">Social Link</label>
      <span class="underline"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="social-add">
  <a href id="add-social"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add Social</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create the id based off of the common string "input-" and append socialX.

```
$(addSocial).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (socialX < maxSocial) {
        socialX++;
        var thisId = "input-" + socialX;
        $(socialWrapper).append('<div class="inputbox"><div class= "inputbox-content"><input id="' + thisId + '" type="text" required /><label for="' + thisId + '">Social Link</label><span class="underline"></span></div></div>');
    }
});
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/7rLjf5b8/6/

Comment: Thanks Man it's work but i change it to be:

var thisId = socialX;